# How to get the real path of shortcut

Tags: python

I used `os.listdir(path)` to get the folder under specific path and found there is a shorcut inside.
How to get the real path of shortcut?

```
Input:
    os.listdir('/tmp/logs')

Output:
    Linux:
        ['12-31-2020_16-59-01-391', 'latest']
    Windows:
        ['12-31-2020_16-59-01-391', 'latest.lnk']
```

Update:

A shortcut is added via the following picture so the real path of shortcut should be another path rather than `/tmp/logs/latest.lnk`, something like `C:\Users\username\Downloads\Temp\logs`.

[image]

Comment: @DanielHao I tried and got `C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\\tmp\\logs\\latest.lnk`

Comment: OK. can you explain what are you looking for (expected results)?  and confirm what's `shorcut`?

Comment: @DanielHao Sorry for not clear question. I've updated in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For linux, we can just use `os.path.realpath` to get the target of symbol link.

But for windows, looks windows shortcut different with linux symbol link, you have to make workaround using `pywin32`, utilize `shell.CreateShortCut(item).Targetpath`.

A minimal example as next.

**test.py**:

```
import platform
import os

system = platform.system()

if system == "Linux":
    print([os.path.realpath(item) for item in os.listdir('.')])
elif system == "Windows":
    import win32com.client
    shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
    print([shell.CreateShortCut(item).Targetpath if item.endswith("lnk") else item for item in os.listdir('.')])
else:
    print('Unknown os.')
```